# Button in tabel rows Angular 5

Tags: angularjs, angular5

Hi there I'm relatively new to Angular so I need to understand some concepts of coding.
I have a table that uses this code to output field data from database model:

```
{
    label: 'Fattura XML',
    width: 120,
    maxWidth: 160,
    minWidth: 120,
    field: 'xml_flag',
    class: 'text-right w_md',
    sort: {
      field: 'xml_flag',
    },
  },

  {
    label: 'Firmata',
    width: 130,
    maxWidth: 130,
    minWidth: 130,
    field: 'file_xml',
    class: 'text-right w_md',
    sort: {
      field: 'file_xml',
    },
  },
```

the values of fields are outputted correctly, but now I need to show in xml_flag a button to download a file, and in the field file_xml a button to upload the signed file. How can I achieve this result? I've been trying all the morning ... but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, once your recieve the data from your service which calls your backend to retrieve the data. Your component should subscribe to that service to recieve the data in the component. Once it's in your component you can use it in your view with the same properties.

Service includes @Injectable()

```
getData(): {
    return this.http.getSomeData();
}
```

Component:

```
Inject the service in the constructor, and have a function invoke the data retrieval
   private storedValue; 
    getDataInComponent(){
        this.service.getData().subscribe(value=>{
            // value is your response if Success it will be value else error
            // Once you have this data you can use it in your component
            this.storedValue = value;
         }, error =>{ // this is your error }
    };
```

In your template

```
<button class="storedValue.class">{{ storedValue.label}}</button>
```

Something like that

Comment: this is in a normal view with norma controller. And it works as well, i know. Here i'm dealing with data table template, field is already populated with data fetched from model. I need to write a function with this data tabel syntax that do somthing like: filed: function() { if(xml_flag === 1){ alert.... Anyway thanks for your time and response